# Locking down an internet cafe user

Tags: windows-10

I have set up or am trying to set up a visitor policy for an Internet café or something similar where you have limited access to a computer so you can only use a browser (this is for a class project, mostly hypothetical).

I have found a couple different paths I can go, one of which is running Microsoft Edge (web browser) as the custom user interface which gives me just a Microsoft Edge window (This is the basis for all my paths since it honestly is the most locked down I have ever seen Windows) but if they minimize or exit out it, it just gives you a black screen.

I have a solution for exiting which is a script that when Edge closes by clicking the cross it logs out the user which is great but they can still minimize it and have a black screen.  I can run Edge in kiosk mode which removes the URL bar (Haven't really got around this one so I'll just start 2 Edge windows, one in kiosk and another in regular full-screen meaning if they exit out of the full-screen one they won't be able to exit out of Edge completely as they will be just stuck with a the kiosk mode edge window.

I'll just set a custom homepage telling the users to just ctrl-n to re-open the window. I wish there was a way to just have that window log user out if they exit it but then they could still minimize it. It also removes the exit so no way for users to log off and the minimize, maximize button.

I have a couple of questions.

I just needed to give hopefully enough context on what I am doing or trying to. I have little to none programing still so I'm kind of hoping that you would be able to help me.

Is there a program would that overlays all windows even over the Edge in kiosk mode that would allow users to logoff.

Sorry for the extra log question here.

Comment: Better asked on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Class exercises are meant for the students.

Comment: Harrymc, yes but I am allowed to ask for help aren't I?

Comment: You generally write your own program as the shell that only allows you to use Internet Explorer or MS Edge. There are companies that sells these. A lot of system configuration is also required.